# How can I get rid of extraneous brackets when importing data from MATLAB?

Tags: import, data, matlab

How can I easily correct this data sequence from MATLAB to one readable in Wolfram Mathematica?

The problem is the 2 outer brackets: `({{ ... }})`

```
data = Import["C:\\Users\\sagarmatha\\OneDrive\\MATHEMATICA\\statistik\\matlabdata.mat","Data"]

({{
  {0., 5.8955}, {0.1, 3.5639}, {0.2, 2.5173}, {0.3, 1.979}, {0.4, 1.899}, 
  {0.5, 1.3938}, {0.6, 1.1359}, {0.7, 1.0096}, {0.8, 1.0343}, {0.9, 0.8435}, 
  {1., 0.6856}, {1.1, 0.61}, {1.2, 0.5392}, {1.3, 0.3946}, {1.4, 0.3903}, 
  {1.5, 0.5474}, {1.6, 0.3459}, {1.7, 0.137}, {1.8, 0.2211}, {1.9, 0.1704}, 
  {2., 0.2636}
}})
```

Comment: Is the sequence read from a file or copied/pasted from Matlab? How long is the sequence?

Comment: I used Import[…] and it's 20 pairs

Comment: Please, could you post the file to be imported so we can see its structure?

Comment: how do I post a file?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add just a few lines of the file you are trying to import. Please use [formatted form](https://wolfr.am/v57OLJu4) for the data and also to share the code you are using to attempt the `Import`.

Comment: @runner thanks for the [edit], it's very useful to see the code you are using. We are still missing the content of `matlabdata.mat` at least the first lines.

Comment: Are you using TraditionalForm? I get your output for `TraditionalForm[{{{0, 1}, {0.1, 2.3}}}]`. If so, you just need to use `Flatten[data, 1]`.

Comment: Incredible :). Thx Carl. I must admit it's a steep learning curve to use mma. So finally I solved my problem :)

Comment: I don't thing I understand what is the real solution. @CarlWoll can you post it as an answer with some explanation?

Comment: Flatten[data,1] took away the outermost parentheses. Or at least made it readable for FindFit. After that I could use FindFit without any problems

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what can be expected when importing mat files: in matlab everything is a matrix, so even when you store a single number into a mat file, it will be actually be a 1x1 matrix and imported to Mathematica as `{{{1.}}}`.

As you can store more than one variable into a mat file, the outermost extra bracket is just a result of `Import` trying to import all stored variables by default as a list. In your case there is only one variable stored so that you get a list of lenth one with the first entry being the matrix that has been stored. Matlab actually stores the variable name used in the session along with the data, so the actual file content becomes more clear whe one uses something like:

```
Import[filename,"LabeledData"]
```

To import the first variable stored in a mat file you could do this:

```
data = First[Import[filename]]
```

or make use of the possibilities to only import the first value stored like this:

```
data = Import[filename,{"Data",1}]
```

Using

```
Import[filename,"Labels"]
```

will show all variable names stored in the mat file, once you know the variable name you want to import you could also use that, like this:

```
data = Import[filename,{"Data","m"}]
```

which would import only the value for the variable named "m".

Note that matlab matrices can have depth larger than two, so you could also get matrices with larger depth with `Import`.